# Iterating over a large dictionary (over 2 billion entries) using python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am very new to python and I want to loop through a dictionary that contains around 2 billion entries. using:

```
for key,value in edge_dict.items():
```

However I am getting out of memory exception because it seems that it tries to load the whole thing and then loop through them. I had this problem with trivial things like:

```
for i in range (2000000000)
```

but I could easily substitute them with

```
while (i < 2000000000):
    i++
```

which solves the problem. However with the dictionary I don't know how to go over the keys without using the for-in iterator. (Note that the keys are strings and the values are ints).

Comment: The operation of `range` changed from between Python 2 and 3. See [Python’s range() Function Explained](http://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for key,value in edge_dict.iteritems():
```

I think is what you want

likewise if

```
for i in range (2000000000)
```

causes a memory error you can use a iterator

```
for i in xrange(2000000000)
```

iterators(and/or generators) only load one item at a time and are consumed as they are iterated ... this fixes many issues one might have with large lists in memory

Comment: Note that this is exclusive to Python 2.x. In Python 3.x, both `dict.items` and `range` return generators, so there is no need for `iteritems` or `xrange` (they actually don't even exist).

Comment: I'll repeat my answer as a comment / warning here, as it is more suited in this format : iterating over such a large dictionary might be a sign of a bad design. See if, in your situation, you can filter the data at the source, whether it's from a database query or something else.